# how to convert strtotime in php to new Date in js

Tags: javascript, php, date, strtotime

For a realtime countdown i use some php variables and echo them in the js like below:

```
$expire_year = '2016';  // year
$expire_month = '8'; // month ( 8 = August)
$expire_day = '14'; // day (14th)
$expire_hour = '2'; // hour ( 1-24)
$expire_minutes = '12'; // minutes
```

i use them in the js like blow:

```
timestamp = new Date(<?php echo $expire_year; ?>, <?php echo $expire_month - 1; ?>, <?php echo $expire_day; ?>, <?php echo $expire_hour; ?>, <?php echo $expire_minutes; ?>),
```

This works fine!

I use php `strtotime` to check if the date really has expired:

```
 $quickpollexpiredate = strtotime("August 14, 2016 2:12"); // set an expiration date
```

So for the countdown timer in js and for the check in php, i have to use 2 different date "structures".

Is it possible to make a check in php so that i have to use only the 5 variables ($expire_year, $expire_month...) with strtotime() or another function?

So actually what i want to achieve is something like this (ofcourse this is wrong, but i hope you understand what i am trying to achieve)

```
$quickpollexpiredate = strtotime($expire_year, $expire_month, $expire_day, $expire_hour, $expire_minutes); // set an expiration date
```

Comment: i didn't really understand. you have to convert `strtotime("August 14, 2016 2:12")` into js date right ?

Comment: yes i only want to use these 5 variables in php and set `strtotime` with it and `new Date` with it

Comment: `new Date(<?=strtotime("August 14, 2016 2:12")?>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a timestamp in php, you can easily use it to set a `Date` object in javascript. You just need to consider that a timestamp in javascript is in milliseconds and not seconds like in php:

```
jsTimestamp = new Date(<?php echo $phpTimestamp; ?> * 1000);
```

or

```
jsTimestamp = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($yourDateString); ?> * 1000);
```

Note that `new Date(...)` also accepts strings, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for more details.

Comment: Great solution! `timestamp = new Date(<?php echo $quickpollexpiredate; ?> * 1000);` works perfect. I now have only 1 variable which i can use for the countdown in js and for the php check. Thanks very much for this answer